# first td value from each tr

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following table shown below, I tried this

```
 $("#tablaMultas tbody tr td:first-child")
```

but I cannot solve.

```
<table id="tablaMultas">
    <thead>
        <tr>

            <th>Minuto inicial</th>
            <th>Minuto linea</th>
            <th>Minuto m. atras</th>
            <th>Valor linea</th>
            <th>Valor m. atras</th>
            <th>Minuto Espera</th>
            <th>Eliminar</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody style="vertical-align: text-top;" id="cuerpoTablaMultas">

        <tr id="filaMulta1" style="border-top: 1px solid #E1EEF4;">
            <input type="hidden" name="valoresFila" value="1-0-0-0-0-1-5">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>
                <p onclick="$(&quot;#filaMulta1&quot;).remove();">
                    <img src="../Maestros/imagenes/borrar.png">
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="filaMulta2" style="border-top: 1px solid #E1EEF4;">
            <input type="hidden" name="valoresFila" value="2-0-0-0-0-1-5">
            <td>2</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>
                <p onclick="$(&quot;#filaMulta2&quot;).remove();">
                    <img src="../Maestros/imagenes/borrar.png">
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and I need create a array with the value from the firts  of each , in this case it would be [1,2], somebody could help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Invalid HTML. You cannot have an input as a direct child of a TR

Comment: Try this `$("#tablaMultas tr td:first-child")`

Comment: @TusharRaj Unfortunately, this will yield only one element..

Comment: i have edited @RajaprabhuAravindasamy

Comment: @TusharRaj Now it seems good.

Comment: why I cannot have an input as a direct child of a TR?

Comment: @Premier see this link for permitted contents inside of a `tr` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try,

```
var values = $("#tablaMultas tbody").find("tr td:first-child").map(function(){ 
     return $(this).text() 
}).get();
```

**Alert:** Your html is completely invalid. `Input tag cannot be a direct child of the tr`. Please refer the following demo to correct the mistake,

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vaemjo7v/1/)

Comment: Why are you using `.find()`?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Not necessary, i just used here for improving the readability. That's all

Comment: @Joeytje50 Your code will not work because of the invalid html..\

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var text = $("#tablaMultas tbody tr td").map(function (i, val) {
    if ($(this).index() == 1) {
        return val.innerHTML
    }
}).get();
console.log(text)
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6t0jgh8a/)